# Import failure SAP BO universe

Tags: business-objects

When I try to import a universe it failure. Already try a reposcan with repair and won't work.

The error it always the same:

> Commit Status=Commit attempted and failed., Promotion Status=Failure : Object has failed to promote. Please see the log for more details. To resolve this problem, please refer to SAP Knowledge Base article KBA 2452002.

Anyone knows what's happening or can help?

I have already restarted the services and the system machines and tried a Reposcan with repair.